# How to connect Android mobile with PC using Teamviewer app using Wifi connection without internet?

Tags: wi-fi, remote-control, remote-access, wifi-direct, teamviewer

I know we can use the teamviewer app to connect to PC using internet connection for remote desktop connection.

But I want to know if it is possible to connect the PC with Phone using the Wifi connection. Both the Android device and the computer are on the same network, and I want to connect them directly, without needing internet access.

Teamviewer has an option to connect to PC's within same LAN. But these settings needs to be configured in the systems to be communicated.

I don't know how to change these settings in my phone. Does anyone know how to achieve this or know any better free app that allows remote desktop connection using wifi, without needing internet access?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need the full version of TeamViewer.

reference: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx

You can establish Remote control sessions on your local network directly by using IP addresses or computer names. By default this feature is deactivated because software firewalls may open an acceptance dialog when configured this way.

To activate the LAN mode in TeamViewer full version and Host module:

```
In the menu click on Extras and then on Options
On the General tab activate Accept incoming LAN connections
```

When selecting accept exclusively it will display the IP-address of the computer in the ID-field.

A connection can now be established using the IP-address or alternatively using the host name.

Comment: Lucifer, I think you don't get the point I am trying to explain here. The answers that you posted are all related to PC(Desktop or laptop), I don't have these "Options" menu, etc in the mobile app. May be you should install the teamviewer app in your phone 1st to understand my question...

Comment: [TeamViewer for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile).  Try installing this app, connect with ur lap using wifi and if you are success, reply with the procedure and I will mark your answer as the "Right Answer". Happy? :P

Comment: Did you buy the full version?

Comment: First, no need for a commercial TeamViewer license (neither mobile nor PC), the unlicensed versions will do. Second, I believe asker wants to know "how to change these settings in my phone", i.e. how to enter the IP address to connect to. Simple: just input the IP address in the Partner-ID field. To enter the `.` between numbers, tap the 'Sym' button on the 'phone-style' keypad, and the keypad layout will change to one which has a button with `.` on it. To continue entering digits, tap the `123` button. Easy as pie.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st thing to do is

1.Connect your android device with your Lap or PC using wifi hotspot.

2.Turn off your mobile internet which was shared with the connected Lap/PC. This makes sure that no internet is shared and only the network connection remains between these devices.

3.Once these 2 steps are done properly, the TeamViewer ID changed from number (Eg:164716358) to its local IP address (Eg:192.168.43.118). So connecting with this IP address connects the mobile and Lap/PC using wifi and this allows remote desktop connection.

But still using this method file transfer was not successful, still remote desktop connection was successful, which solved my issue after lot of research :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to establish a working TeamViewer connection between my android tablet and my windows pc. I use mhotspot to create a wifi hotspot on my windows laptop and connect my android tablet to this new hotspot. TeamViewer is accepting this way immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking to do this too, I have done some research this morning and this is the one that seems to do what I / You want:

https://www.mobizen.com/

Google play link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mvagent&utm_source=androidtapp.com&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=Install

I have not tested it though as I am at work, will check it out tonight.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Apart from that, OP asked specifically for *TeamViewer* – so I'm not sure how your answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can establish Remote control sessions on your local network directly by using IP addresses or computer names. By default this feature is deactivated because software firewalls may open an acceptance dialog when configured this way.

To activate the LAN mode in TeamViewer full version and Host module:

In the menu click on Extras and then on Options On the General tab activate Accept incoming LAN connections 
When selecting accept exclusively it will display the IP address of the computer in the ID-field.

A connection can now be established using the IP-address.

Answer (score -1):

There's another android application, named [Bluetooth Remote PC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.rozkovec.android), which will give you the remote connection to your laptop by using either your android cell phone's bluetooth or wifi connection.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please avoid txtspeak. We have many non-native English speakers here already having difficulties reading it without that. Moreover, without a link to the app, the answer is not very helpful.